# Can I travel using someone else's credit card?

Tags: tickets, spicejet

I booked my Spice Jet air ticket from Dubai using my friend's credit card. What documents do I need when checking in?

Comment: This is not so easy. Did you check the airline credit card usage terms before buying the ticket?

Comment: Airlines rarely even allow this procedure these days.

Comment: @Fattie: Not true. I book (and pay for) flights for family members or occasionally friends all the time

Answer (score 4):

I pulled out a booking I had made with Spicejet around 6 months back and in the second page they had this (emphasis mine)

> Payment by foreign credit cards:
>
> 8. For all foreign (Non-Indian) credit / debit card payments, the card must be produced for physical verification at the airport check-in counter if the passenger is the cardholder.
>      **Incase the cardholder is not traveling, it is mandatory for the passenger to furnish to the airport check-in staff a physical copy of the front side of credit / debit card duly
>      authorized by the cardholder, along with cardholder’s valid proof of identification.** In the absence of such credit / debit card or copy and/or identity mismatch, we will be
>      constrained to refuse the boarding. You may however pay through acceptable alternate mode of payment at the time of check-in and continue your journey.

I am sure the ticket PDF you have received will have similar text.

Keep a copy of credit card(CVV blanked out if you take copy of rear side in addition to front side) with a signed note by cardholder authorizing use of the card along with copy of their passport and you should be fine. Just to be safe, keep equivalent amount of money to pay at check-in if that doesn't work.